# Error: winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel (= 4.14~bionic)

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, wine

Similar to this: [Error: winehq-devel depends wine-devel (=4.5~bionic), Ubuntu 18.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133307/error-winehq-devel-depends-wine-devel-4-5bionic-ubuntu-18-04-2) - trying to install wine from the winehq repo. I initially had trouble with the repo. I did try a recommended fix for held broken packages. It did not report any, and still failed afterward.

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-devel       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel (= 4.14~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I switched from -devel to -stable and it installed correctly. I expect to use -stable; if -devel fails for others it may be appropriate to file a bug report or otherwise contact the developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem myself, until I found out that the latest development version of Wine needs libfaudio0. This is not available in most repositories and is responsible for the dependency error; however the following link will detail how to add the libfaudio0 repository so that Wine devel 4.8 will install:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/05/nstall-wine-4-8-ubuntu-19-04-18-04/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm taking your word for it that this works, because I am happy with the stable version. What I'm curious about is how I could have learned the libfaudio0 library was missing?

Comment: Glad to help!  The way I found out was while visiting the WineHQ offical Ubuntu download page:  https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu - it is written in bold writing at the top.